# Accessing object values passed to function using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite, object

I have a view with a form that asks a user for some details e.g. id, name and surname. To that effect, I have a person object created in a *service* as below to save the users information.

```
var personObject = angular.module("personObject", []);
personObject.service("PersonObject", function () {
    var Person = {
        id: "",
        name: "",
        surname: ""
    };
    return {
        getPerson: function () {
            return Person;
        }
    };
});
```

When the user completes the form the values for *id*, *name* and *surname* are set in the *Person*. This is working as intended and I can view the details back using *get()* in the views controller.

I then pass the person object to another *service* that should insert the user details in a SQLite database table. From my views controller I save the details to Database in my *$scope.save* function.

```
var formDetails = angular.module("formDetailsController", []);
formDetails.controller("FormDetailsController", function ($scope, UpdatePerson, PersonObject) {
    var init = function () {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    };

    init();

    function onDeviceReady() {
    };

    // Save details to database 
    $scope.save = function () {
        var update = UpdatePerson.update(PersonObject.getPerson()); // Get the person object with user defined values and pass to UpdatePerson service
    update.then(
            function (success) {
                // ToDo
            }, function (fail) {
                alert(fail.message);
            });
    };
});
```

My *UpdatePerson* service should insert the person object values to a SQLite table. The table is working as intended and have been tested with some hard coded values. My *update()* function looks as follows (full code given). I am unable to access the person object values however.

```
var update = angular.module("updatePerson", []);
update.service("UpdatePerson", function ($q, Database) {
    // Initialise variables
    var db = Database.init(); // Working
    var updated = "";

    var myFunctions = {
        update: function (MyPerson) {
        alert("MyPerson + // Returns [object Object]
            "\n" + MyPerson.id + // Returns nothing
            "\n" + MyPerson.name + // Returns nothing
            "\n" + MyPerson.surname // Returns nothing);

            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var sql = 'INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tb_person (id, name, surname) VALUES (' + MyPerson.id + ', "' + MyPerson.name + '", "' + MyPerson.surname + '")';
            var success = function (tx, results) {
                deferred.resolve({ updated: true });
            }
            var error = function (tx, err) {
                deferred.reject({
                    updated: false, message: 'An error has occured});
            }

            db.transaction(function (tx) {
                tx.executeSql(sql, [], success, error);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        },
    }
    return myFunctions;
});
```

I am unable to access the values for my *Person* object in my *update()* function as above to insert into the table. It return a blank (not NULL or undefined) - just blank. How do I access the objects values?

Comment: please add the full update method.

Comment: Have added full code snippets now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing declarations

```
    .factory('Service1',['Service2', function (service2,$q, $timeout) {

      var sendDataToOtherService= function (data) {

          service2.updateData(data[0]);

                return true;
            }
          return {
            sendDataToOtherService:sendDataToOtherService
        };

}])
.factory('Service2', function ($q, $timeout) {
        var updateData= function (data) {


          alert(data.name);

                return true;
            }
          return {
            updateData:updateData
        };

});
```

Have a look at demo Link
http://plnkr.co/edit/oz7BA6rTW8vYuIHOYBxL?p=preview